# Prevent double entries in ListView using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

How can we access the items added to a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(printer).aspx)?

The thing I have to do is: add an item to the list view. I want to check if the item to add to the listview is already present in the ListView.

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 17):

The [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ListView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class provides a few different methods to determine if an item exists:

- Using [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.contains.aspx) on the [`Items` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx)
- Using one of the [`FindItemWithText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext.aspx) methods

They can be used in the following manner:

```
// assuming you had a pre-existing item
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("test");
if (!ListView1.Items.Contains(item))
{
    // doesn't exist, add it
}

// or you could find it by the item's text value
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("test");
if (item != null)
{
    // it exists
}
else
{
    // doesn't exist
}

// you can also use the overloaded method to match sub items
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("world", true, 0);
```

Comment: Probably either the OP solved the problem on his own or just found out it worked for him and abandoned this question.

Answer (score 3):

Just add your items and make sure you assign a name. Then
just use the [`ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection to
determine if it's there, like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("Item" + i.ToString("00"));
    item.Name = "Item"+ i.ToString("00");
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.ContainsKey("Item00").ToString()); // True
MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.ContainsKey("Item20").ToString()); // False
```

Comment: This seems to be the way to implement the containment test properly. Why did MS not make it clear that item.Name *is* the key? Or better yet, simply implement their own IEquatable interface on the ListView.Items collection? Bah...   +1 kripto

Comment: I agree with @IAbstract, the comment I have is that the method to use is **ContainsKey** instead of **Contains**...+1

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 ListViewItem itemToAdd;
 bool exists = false;
 foreach (ListViewItem item in yourListView.Items) 
 {
    if(item == itemToAdd)
        exists=true;
 }

 if(!exists)
     yourListView.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

A small correction in Robban's answer

```
 ListViewItem itemToAdd;
 bool exists = false;
 foreach (ListViewItem item in yourListView.Items)
 {
    if(item == itemToAdd)
    {
       exists=true; 
       break; // Break the loop if the item found.
    }
 }
 if(!exists)
 {
    yourListView.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
 }
 else
 {
    MessageBox.Show("This item already exists");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will help to locate a `ListViewItem` within the `ListView` control once you've added it:

```
string key = <some generated value that defines the key per item>;
if (!theListViewControl.Items.ContainsKey(key))
{
    item = theListViewControl.Items.Add(key, "initial text", -1);

}

// now we get the list item based on the key, since we already 
// added it if it does not exist
item = theListViewControl.Items[key];
...
```

**Note**
The `key` used to add the item to the `ListView` items collection can be any unique value that can identify the `ListViewItem` within the collection of items. For example, it could be a hashcode value or some property on an object attached to the `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of multicolumn ListView, you can use following code to prevent duplicate entry according to any column:

Let us suppose there is a class Judge like this

```
public class Judge
    {
        public string judgename;
        public bool judgement;
        public string sequence;
        public bool author;
        public int id;

    }
```

And i want to add unique object of this class in a ListView. In this class id is unique field, so I can check unique record in ListView with the help of this field.

```
Judge judge = new Judge
                {
                    judgename = comboName.Text,
                    judgement = checkjudgement.Checked,
                    sequence = txtsequence.Text,
                    author = checkauthor.Checked,
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(comboName.SelectedValue)
                };

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(judge.judgename);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(judge.judgement ? "Yes" : "No");
            lvi.SubItems.Add(string.IsNullOrEmpty(judge.sequence) ? "" : txtsequence.Text);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(judge.author ? "Yes" : "No");
            lvi.SubItems.Add((judge.id).ToString());
            if (listView1.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText(comboName.SelectedValue.ToString(), true, 0);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    // it exists
                }
                else
                {
                    // doesn't exist
                }

            }
```