# Trapping of Double Entry in ListViewItem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listviewitem

I tried to manage on how to [prevent double entries in ListView Item in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403898/prevent-double-entries-in-listview-using-c). All of them didn't work for me.

I try to based the source code of [Ahmad Mageed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59111/ahmad-mageed) and I was confused of his trappings.
I based his source code to my project

```
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText(txtPLU.Text);
if (item != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item is already been exist!"); //Result if the item has exist in the listview item.
}
else
{
    addToList(); //Its a method to add the product items in the ListViewItem.
    txtBoxPLU.Focus();
}
```

The Behaviour of the runtime is that it only add an item.

Sorry if this is kinda confusing for all of you. I just to trap if the item is already exist in the listview item.

Comment: My Question is that how would I trap an item if the item on the listviewitem exist?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ListView.ListViewItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) has 2 methods that can be used to find if an item is contained in the collection.

The [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

> Example:

```
ListViewItem _item = new ListViewItem();

if (!listView1.Items.Contains(_item))
{
    // TODO: Add to list.
}
else
{
    // Already exists.
}
```