# Prevent Duplicates Insert data in ListView

Tags: c#, listview

This my code :

```
ListViewItem lst1 = new ListViewItem();
lst1.SubItems.Add(txtKodeJob.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(gridLookUpEditJob.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(gridLookUpEditJF.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(txtQty.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(txtTarget.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(deStart.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(deEnd.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(txtDurasiHari.Text);
lst1.SubItems.Add(txtNotes.Text);
listView1.Items.Add(lst1);
```

How to  prevent duplicate data from TextBox in C#?

Comment: Maybe `lst1.SubItems.Distinct()`?

Comment: so i change it from `lst1.SubItems.Add(txtKodeJob.Text);` to `lst1.SubItems.Distinct(txtKodeJob.Text)` ??

Comment: No, change the last line to listView1.Items.Add(lst1.SubItems.Distinct());

Comment: Take a look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403898/prevent-double-entries-in-listview-using-c

Comment: it solve guys,..i use for @mmvsbg method below,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView class provides a few different methods to determine if an item exists:

Using `Contains` on the Items collection
Using one of the `FindItemWithText` methods
They can be used in the following manner:

```
// assuming you had a pre-existing item
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("test");
if (!ListView1.Items.Contains(item))
{
    // doesn't exist, add it
}

// or you could find it by the item's text value
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("test");
if (item != null)
{
    // it exists
}
else
{
    // doesn't exist
}

// you can also use the overloaded method to match sub items
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("world", true, 0);
```